# How can I control the size and position of a new process Window from a WinForms app?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, 32bit-64bit

My WinForms app uses `Process.Start()` to open files in their native app. I want to split the screen in half, showing my WinForms app on one half and the new process on the other. I know I can use `Process.MainWindowHandle` to get the window handle, but how can I set its size and position?

I imagine I have have to use some kind of Windows API, but which one and how? Since this is not really "in my wheelhouse", I am unsure of whether (and how) I need to use different APIs on 64bit Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Windows API method in question is SetWindowPos. You can declare it like so:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private extern static bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, int uFlags);
```

and read about it here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545.aspx

**Added**

Process.MainWindowHandle is the hWnd parameter you will use.
hWndInsertAfter will probably be your own Form's handle (Form.Handle).
You can use the Screen type to access information about the desktop:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx

**Added Thomas' comment**

Make sure you WaitForInputIdle before calling SetWindowPos.

```
Process process = Process.Start(...);
if (process.WaitForInputIdle(15000))
    SetWindowPos(process.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle, ...);
```

The declaration for SetWindowPos above works for both 32- and 64-bit Windows.

Comment: You might want to call WaitForInputIdle on the process before you try to resize the window...

Comment: Thomas, that is exactly what I needed!

Comment: you might want to add Thomas' bit about `Process.WaitForInputIdle`. If you do, I will mark this as the answer.

Also, this is part of the Win32 API. Does it work on a 64bit OS?

Comment: @flipdoubt: Win32 is just the colloquial name for the API; all it's facilities work on 64 bit as well. The official name is the "Windows API".

Comment: Here you can find a version that use an enumeration for the flags and it has XML comments too : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowpos

Comment: What should we set for the last parameter, uFlags?

Comment: @JPProgrammer You should follow the "read about it here" link given in the answer.