# Is controlling windows not owned by your process considered a malware activity?

Tags: winapi, malware, window-management, malware-detection

I am planning to follow one of the suggestions made here to control window dimensions, hide/show and bring to front of a window owned by a different process from my process.

[Window manipulation using window-handle from different process on MS Windows(XP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023942/window-manipulation-using-window-handle-from-different-process-on-ms-windowsxp)

[How can I control the size and position of a new process Window from a WinForms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321535/how-can-i-control-the-size-and-position-of-a-new-process-window-from-a-winforms-a)

Will my process be reported as malware by any of the malware detection software you know?

Will my process need any higher privileges to control the other process window than the highest of the privileges with which my process and the other process are running?

Comment: If your program manipulates windows of a foreign application, then it would most likely be considered annoying, or even malware; if not by any anti-virus software, then almost certainly by the users of your program. Except maybe when your program is some kind of window/desktop manager, ie. when the user explicitly asked for that functionality.

Comment: By the way, these two programs are related, though not as a parent and child. My question is, given that there can be legitimate use case of this approach like window manager or some kind of task switcher, how do malware detection software approach it?

Comment: how malware detection software generally deals with such scenarios is (IMHO) a separate question of its own and shouldn't be asked merely as an aside/comment.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [UI Automation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation) to manipulate another application's window.

This is probably the best way to ensure your manipulating application will not be seen as malware, as UI Automation is 100% part of the OS, not a HACK, supports security. It also application authors to add or remove automation capabilities to their application. See this somewhat related thread here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383600/win32-vs-ui-automation